# Creating a Fibonacci Sequence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, fibonacci

I know that there are several posts on StackOverflow regarding Fibonacci Sequences, but none I have seen seem to directly address the questions I have.

I am trying to list out to the console all numbers in the sequence following the number 2.

I have created a function that I call from within a for loop, but it endlessly lists out a value of "Infinity" rather than the number in the sequence.

To clarify, here is my code:

```
console.log('\nFIBONACCI SEQUENCE UP TO AND INCLUDING 4 MILLION:\n');

var sequence = [1, 2];

var number = 0;

function addToSequence(arr, num)    {

        number = sequence[num] + sequence[num -1];

        sequence.push(number);

        return number;

}   // end addToSequence(num)

var i = 1;

do {

    var nextNum = addToSequence(sequence, i);
    console.log('Next Number in Sequence:', nextNum);

    i++;

}   while (i < 4000000);
```

After the printout of the header, the output I get from this code is something like this:

Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity
Next Number in Sequence: Infinity

I don't know why the number from within the Fibonacci sequence does not print. Any insight you can provide is greatly appreciated.

—Robert Hieger

Comment: Even the 2,000th number in the sequence is bigger than what JS can handle, so it just interprets it as Infinity. Try changing your `while` to `i < 2000` and you'll see the point at which the numbers get too big, although even well before that although it does print numbers they're still too big for full accuracy: the largest integer JS can represent precisely is 9007199254740991.

Comment: You Can Check your Maximum limit by using 
`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` in console.

Comment: Yep, I just ran it with a log of what "i" is, and it made it to the 1473rd index before repeatedly showing Infinity.

Comment: Are you trying to stop at the 4 millionth item in the sequence, or did you want to stop when the value goes above 4 million? That would change your `while` condition to check the nextNum instead of i.

Comment: I am trying to stop when the value goes above 4 million. I will try changing the while condition as you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. It appears this solved the problem. But I am not clear on why my original approach did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fibonacci(n) {
   var a =[0,1];
        
   if (n==1)
    {
    
      console.log(`[${0}]`);
            
    }
        
   else
    {

       for(var i=2;i<n;i++)
          {
    
          a[i] = a[i-1] + a[i-2];
                
          }
            
          console.log(`[${a}]`);
     }
        
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**recursion Fn = (Fn -1) + (Fn - 2)**

```js
let box = {};
function fab(n) {
  if (box[n]) return box[n];
  if (n < 2) return n;
  box[n] = fab(n - 1) + fab(n - 2);
  console.log(`Next Number in Sequence : ${box[n]}`);
  return box[n];
}
fab(10);
```